# R Programming-Market Basket Analysis

Tags: r

After running the inspect command I get the error

> Error in slot(x, s)[i] : subscript out of bounds.

```
basket_rules <- apriori(txn, parameter = list(sup = 0.005, conf = 0.01, target="rules"))
basket.sorted <- sort(basket_rules, by = "lift")
itemFrequencyPlot(txn, topN = 25)
inspect(basket.sorted[1:5])
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`basket.sorted` has presumably less than 5 rules, so `5` is *out of bounds*. See e.g.

```
library(arules)
data("Adult")
basket_rules <- apriori(Adult, parameter = list(sup = 0.9, conf = 0.5, target="rules"))
basket.sorted <- sort(basket_rules, by = "lift")
inspect(basket.sorted[1:5])
# Error in slot(x, s)[i] : subscript out of bounds
basket.sorted
# set of 2 rules
inspect(basket.sorted[1:2])
#     lhs    rhs                 support   confidence lift
# [1] {}  => {capital-gain=None} 0.9173867 0.9173867  1   
# [2] {}  => {capital-loss=None} 0.9532779 0.9532779  1
```